# CUDA Error when training YOLOv4-tiny on Colab: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo

I was following this tutorial to train a YOLOv4-tiny model to detect custom objects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTnZgLsk_DA

However, when I attempt to train the model, I get this error message:

```
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/blas_kernels.cu : () : line: 841 : build time: Jan  7 2022 - 12:01:41 

 CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device: File exists
```

I was running the code on **Colab**, not locally. The GPU used for training is **Tesla K80**.

A common answer is to set the ARCH values to `compute_37, code_37`, but I've already set them this way and keep getting the same error! So what should I do to get this code running?

Link to my Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16EQ6I67OOs1I7rF6PHgBHp1eVHMXXvyO#scrollTo=QyMBDkaL-Aep

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The version of PyTorch you are using doesn’t have built in support for the hardware your Colab session  has been  provisioned with.

Comment: But in the mentioned tutorial they're using Colab, and it doesn't cause the problems I faced... Should I train YOLO locally then, rather than on Colab?

Comment: Colab has different generations of hardware with different GPUs. What works on one Colab  instance might not work on another. You will need to check the hardware you have been given and get a version that works for that

Comment: Could you please explain what I should check? Like, I've already checked compute capability of the GPU... what else?